# How can I configure Angular 5 to support module aliases?

Tags: angular, typescript, module, alias

I would like to alias some folders throughout my project to simplify imports (and actually test my own library before publishing).

So instead of:

```
import { MyClass } from '../mylib/src/somefolder';
```

I want to achieve this:

```
import { MyClass } from '@mylib';
```

I have configured my `tsconfig.json` as follows:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@mylib": ["../mylib/src/"],
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

I have an `index.ts` file in my library's `src` folder as follows:

```
export { MyClass } from "./MyClass";
```

I am using a new project generated with `ng new XX` and ejected with `ng eject`.

I have tried the `tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin` and the `awesome-typescript-loader`'s equivalent, but I am unable to get any combination to work no matter how closely I follow the instructions provided for each - I always get:

> ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(3,40): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@mylib'.

What am I missing?

Comment: Why not use [`npm link`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link) to test your library?

Comment: Would you try "@mylib/*" : ["../mylib/src/*"],

Comment: @R.Richards Thanks, I've looked at that and I will try that, but I'd rather solve why this isn't working as it should and it would keep the solution "clean"!

@Nour Thank you, I tried as you suggested but it didn't seem to work. Would my import remain just `import ... from "@mylib"`?

Comment: Visual Studio Code picks up the alias, but `npm start` doesn't. Here is a zip of a 
 new, non ejected Angular project with a simple alias attempt which fails on `ng serve`: https://www.dropbox.com/s/h8ykhnvl1p5g4ql/AliasTestZip.zip?dl=1

Comment: I am using generator-angular2-library for an angular 5 project and I potentially recommend it https://github.com/jvandemo/generator-angular2-library maybe it can solve your problem

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After much investigation I solved it through trial and error.

The `baseUrl` *must* be `./src` for this to work (where `src` is the root app source code folder in an ejected Angular 5 app), and the paths must be changed to traverse up one more level:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@mylib": [
        "../../mylib/src"
      ]
    },
    ...
}
```

Anything higher in the directory structure than that fails. I am sure someone will be able to explain why this is at some point!

Comment: In and Angular 6 project I didn't have this problem but in Angular 5 it seems like this is the way it works!